# TransmitFile behaves a bit different in SharePoint webpart than in plain asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, download

I always use the following code to stream downloadable pdfs to my users: (in plain asp.net web apps)

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(documentPath + fileName);
Response.End();
```

Now i'm using the same code in a SharePoint 2010 webpart, and it works just as expected. The only thing is that after i've downloaded one file, i cannot click other gridrows that should give me a new download. in other words, i can just download one file and then i have to reload the page to be able to download another file.

Can anyone point me at what (in combination with SharePoint) i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried to use  Response.WriteFile as well, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching for a few hours, tried all kinds of solutions, but none really helped. 
I guess that messing with the response means that you are messing with SharePoint a bit too much.

The workaround i've setup: 
Put the code to modify the response and transmit the file in a separate .aspx file and generate a iframe-tag with the right url and (encrypted) parameters, inject this code to the page by using a literal. 
Works quite nice and simple.

Comment: This is how I did it too. Works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should Flush and Close the response prior to ending it

```
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Also, I haven't tried it specifically in sharepoint, but if the above doesn't work, you might try not ending the response.

Comment: That did not make any difference